# HTML - srcset not working using w? Produce no image?

Tags: html, ios, css, responsive, srcset

Alright, Ive worked in html for a while but now attempting to build a fully responsive site with responsive images/changes according to device. I need this for a client and was going to do with media calls in CSS but found a tutorial on srcset claiming it is the correct way to accomplish this.

My person has specified they want a separate image to load for the following:
- desktop
-iphone 6s
-iphone 6plus/ipad pro
-other/smaller mobile

My image has a margin of 20 px on each side, meaning I need the image to be the width of the screen - 40px.

I went to https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions and followed  a tutorial on src set and came up with these sizes, taking into account when to multiply by 2 or 3 for resolution (I think I have gotten a handle on how pixels/resolution works):

- Desktop: 768px
- iphone 6s: 670px
- iphone 6 plus:1122px
- other mobile: 240px

I then wrote the following having read the browser will switch to the correct image based on screen size:

```
<img src="/images/home-desktop.jpg" srcset="/images/home-iphone6s.jpg 670w, /images/iphone6plus.jpg 1122w, /images/allMobile.jpg, 240w, /images/home-desktop.jpg 768w">
```

however nothing at all is working, no matter how I stretch the browser.I get this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? the values with the w are the sizes of the images - this isn't supposed to be screen size right? how can I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Remove the slash before images in src and srcset will get the image to appear.

```
src="/images/home-desktop.jpg"
```

to

```
src="images/home-desktop.jpg"
```

or, depending on location

```
src="../images/home-desktop.jpg"
```

Here's an example I made. Scale it with the browser and the images will change.

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/TvWMgVA.jpg" srcset="http://i.imgur.com/5aVGfyV.jpg 670w, http://i.imgur.com/IfcHwWe.jpg 1122w, http://i.imgur.com/dHDGSBO.jpg 240w, http://i.imgur.com/JVDFaMT.jpg 768w">
```

Remove the comma after allMobile.jpg,

Comment: @skyguy What is the full path to your image? Is it on a web server or local computer?

Comment: the full path is what i have images/home-desktop.jpg it is local. The default (not in srcset) shows up but only at first when I remove the slashes. Why is this

Comment: @skyguy I've updated the answer. Remove the comma after allMobile.jpg and also test my example.